# how do i check a user input string with email format

Tags: c++

How do i check if user input a string with an email format,

E.g. `Ted@Ted.com`

I want to check if there's an "@" and "."

other than using ispunct function

Comment: Validating an email address is [quite a complicated task](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

Comment: email syntax has a lot of rules. Much more than just having a '@' and a '.'

Comment: Not all valid addresses contain "."

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::string::find_first_of`.

```
// Check that the string contains at least one '@' and a '.'
// after it. This will have lots of false negatives (but no
// false negative), like "a@b@c.com" or "toto@com.".
bool is_email(std::string const& address) {
    size_t at_index = address.find_first_of('@', 0);
    return at_index != std::string::npos 
        && address.find_first_of('.', at_index) != std::string::npos;
}
```

But usual disclaimer with parsing email addresses: this is a really complex topic, because a valid email address is a strange beast. Check [RFC 5322](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc5322.html) for specification of what is a valid address.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions, you can evaluate against

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$
```

which matches **nearly all** legal email addresses. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

If you're using C++11 you can use `std::regex`, otherwise you'll have to use a 3rdparty regex parser such as `boost::regex`